# GSON response return the whole page code including json data

Tags: java, json, jsf, gson

i'm working on an android application that communicate with a jsf application to get the data from database, when i run the android application it shows an error

```
com.google.gson.stream.malformedjsonexception : Use jsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed json
```

the full error :

```
05-02 16:03:51.772: E/(837): [{"description":"CAISSES","nomCat":"CAISSES","photo":"R.JPEG","idCat":1},{"description":"CAISSEDETAIL","nomCat":"CAISSEDETAIL","photo":"P.JPEG","idCat":2}]<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/pime/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-hot-sneaks" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/pime/faces/javax.faces.resource/fa/font-awesome.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.2.RC3" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" /><!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/pime/faces/javax.faces.resource/js/html5shiv.js?ln=bsf"></script><script src="/pime/faces/javax.faces.resource/js/respond.js?ln=bsf"></script><![endif]--><script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){}</script></head></html>
```

as it shows from the error it load the whole page code including the json data.

**ANDROID**

```
class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, StringBuffer> {

        @Override
        protected StringBuffer doInBackground(String... args) {
            String url = args[0];
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = getHttpResponse(url);
            return stringBuffer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(StringBuffer result) {
            Log.e("", result.toString());
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Categorie[] categories = gson.fromJson(result.toString(), Categorie[].class);
            for(Categorie c : categories){

                Log.e("", c.getNomCategorie());
                cats.add(c);
            }
            listCatModel.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

**the xhtml that i call from android :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

      <h:head></h:head>
    <f:metadata>

    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginBean.authentifier}" />
</f:metadata>
</html>
```

**Method from backing bean :**

```
public  @ResponseBody void  authentifier() throws IOException {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ext = context.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ext.getResponse();


        PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;

        List<Categories> listCategories = iCategorieManager.listCategories();


        for (Categories cats : listCategories) {
             jsonObject=new JSONObject(cats);
             jArray.put(jsonObject);
        }

        writer.println(jArray);


    }
```

**WEB.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/Beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>

hot-sneaks


    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
     <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Last-Modified</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I think the problem is related to how you've set up your REST service within your JSF application. Not related to GSON. Post a bit more from your backend.

Comment: @NazaretK. i added more code from the backed as you asked

Comment: @NazaretK. please how to call the REST service url directly?

Comment: Can you post your web.xml please? Are you using Spring mvc? Do you have a DispatcherServlet?

Comment: @NazaretK. i just added the web.xml and i'm not using DispatcherServlet

Comment: There might be a quick fix to this. Can you please try to add context.responseComplete() in the end of your authentifier method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110850/discussion-between-nazaret-k-and-hamza-toussi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are calling the JSF view, it is calling the managed bean, which is writing the json to the response and then the JSF view is also rendering its html to the response. This of course results in an invalid json response.

One option would be to call the REST service directly, not through the JSF view. But this would require you to setup spring-mvc DispatcherServlet.

A quicker fix would be to instruct JSF that you are done with writing the response and it shouldn't render anything else. For that you can use the [responseComplete](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete()) method of FacesContext in the end of your authentifier method.

```
context.responseComplete();
```

Comment: thank you so much, context.responseComplete()  did the job